# Flip/transpose a heatmap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Code bellow generates heatmap that goes from bottom left to top right

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(111)

n <- 10
m <- matrix(rnorm(n^2), n, n)
m <- cor(m)
m <- melt(m)

ggplot(m, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
    geom_tile()
```

[image]

How can I modify my data (probably modify melt result) so heatmap would go from top left to bottom right, for result like this [image]

Comment: `... aes(rev(Var1), Var2, fill = value) ...` ? Or, `+ scale_x_reverse()`?

Comment: Just do: ggplot(m, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
    geom_tile()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A terrible solution compared to @Axeman's (but more fun) is to apply a rotational transformation matrix to the data.

To understand what kind of transformation we need, I plotted only the diagonal (value=1) points on a 3D scatter plot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The rotational matrix about the z (value) axis
[image]

Including the added constant, the final equation is

[image]

There is probably a better way to vectorize this transformation, but this is how I did it.

```
rot_m <- matrix(c(0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1),3,3)

ftransform <- function(x){
   t(rot_m %*% as.numeric(matrix(m[x,],3,1)) + matrix(c(0,11,0),3,1))
 }

foo <- lapply(1:nrow(m),ftransform)

foo <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,foo))
names(foo) <- c("Var1","Var2","value")
ggplot(foo, aes(Var1,Var2,fill=value)) + 
   geom_tile()
```

[image]

EDIT:  Apologies about the weird image format/layout.

Comment: Nice. But m is not defined in your script.

Comment: m was defined in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
ggplot(m, aes(aes(reorder(Var1, desc(Var1)), Var2, fill = value)) + 
    geom_tile()
```

[result plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ftmX.jpg)