# Change diagonal within geom_raster() from bottom-left-to-top-right to top-left-to-bottom-right

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-raster

I have created a heatmap using `geom_raster()` within `ggplot`.  Currently, the diagonal goes from the bottom left to the top right.  I went to flip the diagonal so that it goes from the top left to the bottom right.

I've tried to reverse the order `x` and `y`, but that just reversed the order they appear on the axis and didn't change the diagonal.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=being_rated, y=providing_rating, fill = mean_value)) + 
  geom_raster()
```

I've also tried the suggestions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624374/flip-transpose-a-heatmap-in-ggplot2), but while the diagonal was flipped, the the X and Y values no longer matched up like they should. E.g., Team 1 & Team 1 should be blank, Team 2 & Team 2 should be blank...This produced Team 1 & Team 15 blank, Team 2 & Team 14 blank, etc.

This is what my chart looks like now:
[image: geom_raster]

This is what I want it to look like:
[image: geom_raster_desired]

Here the the data that I'm working with:

```
data <- structure(list(providing_rating = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L), .Label = c("Team1", "Team2", "Team3", "Team4", "Team5", "Team6", 
"Team7", "Team8", "Team9", "Team10", "Team11", "Team12", "Team13", 
"Team14", "Team15"), class = "factor"), being_rated = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c("Team1", 
"Team2", "Team3", "Team4", "Team5", "Team6", "Team7", "Team8", "Team9", "Team10", 
"Team11", "Team12", "Team13", "Team14", "Team15"), class = "factor"), 
    mean_value = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.25, 2.75, 1.75, 2, 2.75, 2.25, 
    2.25, 2.5, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 2.75, 2, 2.25, 1.75, 2.5, 2.25, 
    2.25, 2.25, 1.5, 1.66666666666667, 1.75, 2, 2, 2, 2.75, 2.33333333333333, 
    3, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
    2, 2.33333333333333, 2, 2.66666666666667, 2, 2.66666666666667, 
    3, 2.66666666666667, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 
    2.5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 3, 2.66666666666667, 
    2.33333333333333, 1.83333333333333, 1.83333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 
    1.83333333333333, 2.16666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 3, 
    1.6, 1.8, 1.8, 2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 2, 2, 1.6, 2.8, 1.6, 2.6, 
    2.8, 1.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 
    1.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 
    1.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 3, 
    2, 2.33333333333333, 3, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.6, 2.6, 2.8, 2.4, 
    2.4, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.33333333333333, 2, 2.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
    1.66666666666667, 2, 2, 2.33333333333333, 2, 2, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 3, 3, 2.66666666666667, 
    2.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
    2, 2.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
    2.66666666666667, 3, 2.5, 2.25, 2, 2, 2, 2.25, 2.25, 2, 2.5, 
    1.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 2, 2, 2.5, 
    1.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 2.25, 
    3, 2, 2.75, 2.5, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 3, 2, 2.66666666666667, 
    3, 3, 2.66666666666667, 3, 2.66666666666667, 3, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 3, 
    2.66666666666667)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -210L))
```